# php mysql updating a column only where there are duplicates in an if statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, if-statement

I have this problem i can't seem to solve. I'm kinda new at programming so it could be really easy but i couldn't find anything. I have a big array through which I loop and if there are duplicates they need to be set to false in a column called address_correct. Here is my code:

```
    $sql1 = "SELECT street, entity_id FROM adresfix";

    $arraycorrect = [];
    $arrayincorrect = [];
    $i = 0;

    $db_query = $db->query($sql1);
    $adres_rows = $db_query->fetch_all();
    var_dump($adres_rows);

    foreach ($address_rows as $address) {
        if (in_array($address_rows[$i][0] , $arraycorrect)){
            echo "Good";
            array_push($arrayincorrect, $address_rows[$i][0]);
            $sql = "UPDATE adresfix SET address_correct = 'false' WHERE";
        } else {
            array_push($arraycorrect, $address_rows[$i][0]);
            echo "False";   
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

I have no idea what is should put after where in the sql query to make sure only the duplicates are updated. Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: WHERE street = $address_rows[$i][0]

Comment: @Nero It doesn't work because the array has to be converted into string but i don't know how.

Comment: can u var_dump $address_rows[$i][0] and check what it is.also foreach ($address_rows as $address) should be foreach ($adres_rows  as $address).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, but I am not sure what your endgoal is. The most easy thing to do to remove duplicates is create a new table and insert all unique records in that new table, like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE adress_unique LIKE adresfix;  

INSERT INTO address_unique  
SELECT * FROM adresfix  
GROUP BY street,number,city; // Combination of columns that contains duplicate values.
```

Eventually, after reviewing, you could remove the old table and rename the new one:

```sql
DROP TABLE adresfix;  
ALTER TABLE address_unique RENAME TO adresfix;
```

Comment: thank you. I'm sorry i'm not very good at explaining in english cause i'm dutch. The only thing is that my endgoal isn't to delete teh duplicates but marking them. Every row has a column called address_correct which is automatically true. Now i need to update all the rows to false where the row is a duplicate.

Comment: No worries, I'm Dutch too :) I will add another answer with a subquery example

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the select query to get all duplicate rows, based on multiple columns (assumption), is:

```sql
SELECT * FROM adresfix AS a1
INNER JOIN adresfix AS a2
WHERE (
    a1.street = a2.street
  AND
    a1.number = a2.number
  AND
    a1.city = a2.city
)
```

Now, if you want to update those rows, you should add this query to the update query, as a subquery or join query. Example:

```sql
UPDATE adresfix
SET address_correct = false
WHERE entity_id IN (
  SELECT entity_id FROM (
    SELECT a1.entity_id 
    FROM adresfix AS a1
    INNER JOIN adresfix a2
    WHERE (
        a1.street = a2.street
      AND
        a1.number = a2.number
      AND
        a1.city = a2.city
      )
    ) AS foo
)
```

See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8899eb/2